# Can I fix Nikon D500 AF button with hot glue?

Tags: nikon, repair, back-button-autofocus

The AF-on button of my Nikon D500 camera popped off the camera yesterday. It still works if I hold it with a finger and click, but I can't really shoot while holding it all the time.

Can I safely put a small amount of hot glue in the button's tip and try to attach it again? I really don't know how to fix it, and I'll need the camera tomorrow morning. =(

[image: Here's a picture of the button]
[image: inside button]

Comment: Is this a button you use frequently? Can it be remapped? Consider leaving it alone until you have more time to work on it. The last thing you need is to make the camera inoperable. You could put some tape over it to hold it in place temporarily so it can be used tomorrow.

Comment: Hi @xiota, thanks replying so quickly. I  didn't think of remapping. I made it and it worked great!  I've attached a photo of my camera's new hole. Is it safe to glue it?  :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Consider leaving it alone until you have more time to work on it. The last thing you need is to make the camera inoperable, since you need it tomorrow.
2. If this is a button you use frequently, try to remap it for now. You can also try putting some tape over it to hold it in place temporarily.
3. I can't tell what's exposed in the image you've attached. The button uses a conductive pad to connect the circuit. If what's exposed is the circuit board, then glue would prevent the button from working.

   If what's exposed is the top of the pad, then it would probably be safe to glue the button cap back on. If the button works when you press it with something non-conductive, it would be safe to glue. Be careful that you don't glue the button stuck down.
4. Replacement buttons are available. You can follow this guide to get the back of the camera off – Life Pixel: [Nikon D500 DIY Digital Infrared Conversion Tutorial](https://www.lifepixel.com/tutorials/infrared-diy-tutorials/life-pixel-nikon-d500-diy-digital-infrared-conversion-tutorial).

   [image: replacement button]